How to get Java console scan 2 strings separated by TAB key
I cannot type the TAB key into the console for 2 strings separated by the tab key, i used the split method but it didn't work. The Java console does not accept the TAB key.
Here's a snippet of my code
String[] data;
String description, amount;
    
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
System.out.println("Enter the description, followed by a [TAB] key, and then the amount: ");
data = scan.nextLine().split("\\t");
description = data[0];
amount = data[1];
    
    
System.out.println("You have entered: " + description + " and " + amount)


Please be more specific. Exactly what type of console are you using?

I use BlueJ for my code editor

You can't use a tab character in consoles usually. Choose a different one

if this not working you can use BufferedReader to take the input
for example
        String[] data;
        String description = "", amount = "";

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            data = br.readLine().split("\\t");
            description = data[0];
            amount = data[1];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


        System.out.println("You have entered: " + description + " and " + amount);

this should work and do the required job

The problem is not what classes you use to read the input. The problem is consoles (rather like text fields) are not designed to hold tabs
